# ImageView is not showing captured Image using Camera in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

I am trying to choose an image for registration. When clicking the `ImageView`, the user will be given a choice between taking a picture or choosing from his/her gallery. When the user chooses the gallery option, it will display the selected image. When the user chooses the camera option, the `ImageView` does not display the image. Below is my code for the `OnActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imgdata) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imgdata);
        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && imgdata != null) {
            selectedimage = imgdata.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedimage);
                Bitmap yourselectedimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                imgchild.setImageBitmap(yourselectedimage);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && imgdata != null) {
            camImg =(Bitmap) imgdata.getExtras().get("img");
            try {
                imgchild.setImageBitmap(camImg);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

The `ImageView` should display the taken picture from the camera.

Comment: Have you checked if `camImg` is `null` or not yet?

Comment: Have a deep read of [photobasics](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like this

```
    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code, I think it's highly likely that `camImg` is null because the way you extract bitmap from `Intent` is incorrect.

`Bitmap` implements `Parcelable`, so you need to extract it like this:

```
camImg = (Bitmap) imgdata.getParcelableExtra("img");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Set image like this

```
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);


   // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
   Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
   File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
   Log.e("path", finalFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

To get image path where it is stored

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with Android Marshmallow, in my case, it is happening due to large bitmap so I figured out with the following code by resizing bitmap

```
    final int maxSize = 960;
    int outWidth;
    int outHeight;
    int inWidth = CameraActivity.bitmap.getWidth();
    int inHeight = CameraActivity.bitmap.getHeight();
    if(inWidth > inHeight){
        outWidth = maxSize;
        outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
    } else {
        outHeight = maxSize;
        outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
    }
        iv_captured_image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(CameraActivity.bitmap, outWidth, outHeight, false));
```